# too many levels of trigger recursion when inserting in an INSERT trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I want to create a UniqueIdentifier for each new row created or inserted in a SQLite3 table. I have searched for solutions here on this forum and I found two "Select Statements" that create such a UniqueIdentifier. The code is as following:

```
SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v);
```

When I enter the SQL in Firefox SQLite Manager it works just fine a delivers the value I want to use.

I tried to use that created value into a table and it does not work. I always get the error message "Too many recursions..."

I used the following SQL code to create the table which worked just fine.

```
CREATE TABLE "SampleTable" (
"SampleTableID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
"SampleTableUID" varchar(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
"Name" varchar(50), 
)
```

Then I tried to use the following SQL code to create the Trigger and that did not work. In one of my trials I create a data record first and then I created the trigger and it seems to work when I add a second data record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "UID" AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable" FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("SampleTableUID") 
SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v); END
```

What do I do wrong?

I want to create this UniqueIdentifier with the very first data record and with all following records.

---

CORRECT CODE IS AS FOLLOWING

---

Thanks to the help of CL I found the answer myself. The correct working solution is:

```
    CREATE TABLE "SampleTable" (
"SampleTableID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
"SampleTableUID" varchar(32), 
"Name" varchar(50) 
)


CREATE TRIGGER "UID" 
AFTER INSERT ON "SampleTable" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE "SampleTable"
SET "SampleTableUID" = (SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v))
WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid();
END


INSERT INTO "SampleTable" ("Name") VALUES ("Name1");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INSERT statement adds a new record to the table.

To change something in the inserted row, you must use an UPDATE statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UID
AFTER INSERT ON SampleTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.SampleTableUID IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE SampleTable
    SET SampleTableUID = (SELECT whatever...)
    WHERE SampleTableID = NEW.SampleTableID;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I tried the code and it is accepted but the value of the select statement is not updated in the respective data field. It remains empty when I add the first record and after I add a new record too.

Comment: What are you inserting into `SampleTableUID`?

Comment: I want to insert the value created by the SELECT statement:

Comment: SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v);

Comment: What are you inserting into `SampleTableUID` with the original INSERT statement?

Comment: OH, With the first record the SampleTableUID is empty, it should be filled by the SELECT statement too?

Comment: What is the INSERT statement you're using?

Comment: I am not using a insert statement yet, I am adding the first record using the Firefox SQLite Manager after I have created the SampleTable

Comment: Is the inserted value NULL or an empty string? Try without the WHEN clause.

Comment: It is "Empty String" - I tried without When clause and it did not change, still empty?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code lead me to the correct solution.